# How can I add a TypeScript interface for the bootstrap modal constructor

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm working at converting an existing codebase to use TypeScript.

Our code includes this hack (it's a workaround for a bootstrap bug):

```
jQuery().modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

Typescript doesn't like this, and gives this error:

> The property 'Constructor' does not exist on value of type '{
>   (options?: ModalOptions): JQuery; (options?:
>   ModalOptionsBackdropString): JQuery; (command: string): JQuery; }'.

These are the pertinent type definitions (from bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped):

```
interface JQuery {
    modal(options?: ModalOptions): JQuery;
    modal(options?: ModalOptionsBackdropString): JQuery;
    modal(command: string): JQuery;
}
```

...but I can't work out how to add to or modify this interface definition to prevent the error.

Comment: I used this file and it works well 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot define a member var + function with same name. i.e. the following is a compiler error:

```
interface foo {
    a();
    a:number;
}
```

Meanwhile you can do :

```
(<any>jQuery()).modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};
```

If TypeScript had type unions, which it doesn't (you can vote for these here https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1364) you could potentially do:

```
interface foo {
    a:()=>void | number;
}
```